# Dynamically modify the content of a Sliding Drawer

Tags: android

I would like to be able to change the content of a sliding drawer when the user clicks on a radio button .  For example if user checks radio button "A"  and then opens the sliding drawer , it contains 2 edit boxes and a spinner. After the sliding is closed if the user clicks radio button "B" and opens the slider again , now it contains a radio group and an edit text.

The sliding drawer is closed when the user presses the radio buttons.

Could someone suggest an idea in towards achieving  this?

Answer (score 3):

You will need your context the view your drawer resides in.  Then do something like this

If clicked 'A':

```
ViewGroup newContent = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.myDrawerContent);
currentContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.theNewLayoutForA, newContent);
```

If clicked 'B':

```
ViewGroup newContent = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.myDrawerContent);
currentContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.theNewLayoutForB, newContent);
```

Essentially all you are doing is getting your Sliding Drawer content view and inflating the new content into it.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`close()`](http://goo.gl/BsJ7H) on the `SlidingDrawer`.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough . I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: `SlidingDrawer` is a `ViewGroup`. Use the methods on `ViewGroup` to change the contents, such as `addView()` and `removeView()`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and put the change in a touch event.

Comment: This is a bit brief. Could you expand on how this would help?

Comment: Hi Sean, welcome to Stack Overflow.  As it stands, this answer is probably too short (in length and detail) for Stack Overflow.  Check out the [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for help with answering.